# How to build a proxy layer for SOAP/XML webservices

Tags: wcf, web-services, proxy

I need to capture and run realtime analysis on messages being exchanged between various web services implemented in Java and client apps.  The server code and config can not be modified and is hosted on various servers.

Is it possible to build a proxy layer that will take all calls from the client app and route them to actual web services.

So it needs to do the following:

1. Accept a config file containing endpoints for various web services that need to be proxied
2. For each end point, generate a proxy URL
3. The client apps will point to these proxy URLs
4. The proxy layer will listen to traffic on these proxy URLs, and route them to real end points.
5. Track all SOAP traffic in between the client and services and run the necessary analysis.

I considered SoapUI but it does not seem to provide enough control that I need for realtime analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with [WCF Routing service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517421.aspx). Once you have working communication you can add some custom message processing through custom behaviours or channels to grab SOAP messages and do your analysis.

Comment: This is useful link. I will take a look.  Thanks.